# Difference-in-differences of standard deviation

Tags: difference-in-difference, volatility

I am hypothesizing that a certain event caused prices of commodity A to become more volatile. I obtained monthly price data for commodity A as well as a price index for a larger bucket of products similar to commodity A (let's call it B) which I will use as a control. I have 10 years (120 periods) of data for both before and after the event.

I am using a simple percentage change to calculate monthly returns on these prices, and defining volatility as the standard deviation of these returns. Using the four sets of data (pre-event A, post-event A, pre-event B, post-event B), how can I set up a difference-in-differences analysis to prove that there is a significant increase in volatility in commodity A?

I see that usually difference-in-differences analyses are conducted using OLS regression. Is it possible to deviate from that norm and simply calculate each of the four standard deviations and use f-tests for hypothesis testing?

Thank you!